# Create new CSV files in python from the CSV files having same values in the column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am writing a python script to read multiple csv files from a folder. I need to merge the csv files according to the values present in one column (3rd column) and create new csv files from them.

For eg: I have 3 csv files like below:

csv 1:            csv 2:         csv 3:

2  4  1994    4      4      1995    2      4      1997
2  4  1994    0      4      1995    2      4      1997

9  0  1994    9      6      1995    9      0      1998

6  7  1994    6      9      1996    6      7      1998

6  4  1995    4      2      1996    6      4      1998

6  3  1995    4      1      1997    6      3      1998

6  5  1995    0      5      1997    6      5      1999

8  7  1995    7      8      1997    8      7      1999

The output should look like:

O/P 1:            O/P 2:         O/P 5:

2      4      1994            6      4      1995    9      0      1998
2      4      1994            6      3      1995    6      7      1998
9      0      1994            6      5      1995    6      4      1998

6      7      1994            8      7      1995    6      3      1998

           4    4      1995
           0      4      1995
           9    6      1995

O/P 3:            O/P 4:         O/P 6:

6      9      1996            4      1      1997            6      5      1999
4      2      1996            0      5      1997            8      7      1999
           7    8      1997

I would really appreciate if someone me helps with this! Any suggestions will be really helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use a dict with the unique values from the 3rd row as keys and a data frame with the respective rows as values and append to the dataframes as you read the files

Comment: "I am writing a python script" - please include the code you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used glob to automate this search for the .csv files, but if they were already initialized in some variable you can merge them and use only the part of `for year in all_csv['YEAR'].unique()...`

```py
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = "/home/gustavo/" # path your csv files are (in my example is store in /home/gustavo)

all_csv = pd.DataFrame()
for file in glob.glob(path + "*.csv") : # *.csv search for all csv files in path
    all_csv = all_csv.append(pd.read_csv(file, header = None), ignore_index = True)

all_csv = all_csv.rename(columns = {0 : 'A', 1 : 'B', 2 : 'YEAR'})

# Filter for each year value and transform to csv 
for year in all_csv['YEAR'].unique() :
    all_csv[all_csv['YEAR'] == year].to_csv(f'{year}.csv', index=False)
```

Output : 
[image]